# Object Replication C# - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, object

I am pretty much a front-end developer, so Web Devolopment is my comfort zone. But when it comes to something less "browser", i get stucked.
I'm starting now with c#, and trying to understand some basics to get going, so i've made a simple contact list prototype (i am using Windows Forms):

[image]

**The problem:**

I wanna make a program that's is similar to a contact list; you have the name input, the number and a "add" button. And each contact renders with a "x" button to delete itself from the list.
When you click the "add" button, it creates the contact in the list and displays it like this:

[image]

The thing is, i don't know how to make this object and create a "copy" of that. I mean my problem is with the "model".
Unlike in Web Development that you make an object structured in HTML, then to style it you only need to add classes to each box(and with javascript change the information),
in VS with C# it looks pretty different, there's no DOM where i can render my pre-created objects and no browser engine to do the work for me.

**Question:**

How can I make a contact's model like belows, in a way that its replicable, and how do i render it inside a list?

[image]

Comment: Research "`UserControl`"s

Comment: See: [Make an owner-drawn ListBox in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/11/make-an-owner-drawn-listbox-in-c/).

Comment: WPF and WinUI (with XAML) may be more accessible with only a Web development background. Layout and styling of controls or formatting data through templates is a lot closer to HTML/CSS.

Comment: AS in the first comment, make a UserControl (has its own Designer), styled as your *contact* object. You can add a Constructor that accepts the values it should display. When you need a new object, just create a new instance of it (using the `new` keyword), pass the data in its Constructor (or set custom public properties, it's ~the same thing), then add this new Contact object to, e.g., a FlowLayoutPanel that will present the new object in a sort of list automatically. -- The you'll have to decide how you find or filter these contacts and show them to the User... different story :)